# window form when form load unable direct navigate to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

when frmlogin form load i would like to direct navigate to another form, but it will just show frmLogin, unable to show form1

```
 private void frmLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //if else condition to navigate to another form 
     form1 frm = new form1();
     frm.Show();
     this.Hide();
 }
```

currently when click on button only able to navigate to another form

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      frmSelectProfile frm = new frmSelectProfile();
      frm.Show();
      this.Hide();
 }
```

Please advice me on how can i navigate to another form when page load.

Answer (score 1):

Form has "shown" event, use from it:

```
  private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     var frm = new form1();
     this.Hide();
     frm.Show();
  }
```